# How to declare 'self' return in Python method signature

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this class with method `just_test`

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def just_test(self, a: int) -> MyClass:
        return self
```

I'm not able to declare at the method signature that I return the object I'm working on (the `-> MyClass` part)

I'm getting "Unresolved Reference MyClass" error from PyCharm.

I've also tried `-> self` at the method signature, but I get the same error.

I'm using python 3.10

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your file put this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

This will allow the name `MyClass` to be used inside its implementation.